# rename() does not rename a file on useage

Tags: c++

I'm using rename() and variables to include the save data path, but rename isnt actually renaming my files when using rename(oldUtiniName.c_str(), newUtiniName.c_str())

```
void changeHumanName() {
    string oldHumanName;
    string newHumanName;
    ifstream utini;
    ofstream tempUtini;
    ifstream file0;
    ofstream tempFile0;

     string oldUtiniName = saveDirPath + "\\temp_utini.txt";
     string oldFile0Name = saveDirPath + "\\temp_file0.txt";
     string newFile0Name = saveDirPath + "\\file0";
     string newUtiniName = saveDirPath + "\\UNDERTALE.ini";

     // string saveDirPath is declared globally
    utini.open(utIniPath);
    tempUtini.open(saveDirPath + "\\temp_utini.txt");
    file0.open(file0Path);
    tempFile0.open(saveDirPath + "\\temp_file0.txt");

    clear();

    if (!utini.is_open() || !file0.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open UNDERTALE.ini and file0!" << endl;
        return;
    }

    cout << "Please enter your current humans name: "; cin >> oldHumanName;
    cout << "Please choose a new human name: "; cin >> newHumanName;

    string line;
    while (getline(file0, line)) {
        size_t pos = line.find(oldHumanName);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            line.replace(pos, oldHumanName.length(), newHumanName);
        }
        tempFile0 << line << endl;
    }

    while (getline(utini, line)) {
        size_t pos = line.find(oldHumanName);
        if (pos != string::npos) {
            line.replace(pos, oldHumanName.length(), newHumanName);
        }
        tempUtini << line << endl;
    }

    utini.close();
    tempUtini.close();
    file0.close();
    tempFile0.close();

    if (rename(oldUtiniName.c_str(), newUtiniName.c_str()) != 0) {
        cout << "Error renaming UNDERTALE.ini. Changes might not be applied." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "UNDERTALE.ini renamed successfully." << endl;
    }

    if (rename(oldFile0Name.c_str(), newFile0Name.c_str()) != 0) {
        cout << "Error renaming file0. Changes might not be applied." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "file0 renamed successfully." << endl;
    }

}
```

Not sure why it wont rename my files, Maybe because there are files there that are already named file0 and UNDERTALE.ini?

Comment: What is the value of `errno` after the call to `rename` fails?

Comment: where would i call `errno`?

Comment: `errno` is a global variable that holds the last error code of C library function calls like `rename`. When you are reporting the rename failure, add something like `cout << "errno=" << errno << '\n';`

Comment: i'm reciving a 17 from errno

Comment: That sounds like the target file already exists, as you suggested.

Comment: and to delete the existing files after they have been closed?

Comment: You can delete a file with the C library function `remove()`

Comment: so something like this? `remove(utIniPath);`

Comment: Are you using libc `rename()` from `stdio.h` or `std::rename` from `cstdio`? Probably `std::filesystem::rename()` will be better choise because of specified behavior if new name exists.

Comment: I just included the iostream header as well as string and fstream

Comment: For `std::rename`: if new_filename exists, the behavior is implementation-defined. For `std::filesystem::rename`: new_p is first deleted, then, without allowing other processes to observe new_p as deleted, the pathname new_p is linked to the file and old_p is unlinked from the file. This differs from removing file and renaming then.